# Firebase Authentication current user null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

For some reason `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` is null even though the user have to be logged in at this point.

I have followed the official documentation to implement authentication and its logging in as expected but getting the current user after login is null.

Here is how I am authenticating:

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        //user already signed in if non-null
        auth.currentUser?.let {
            gotToMainActivity()
        }

        // Check for existing Google Sign-In account, if the user is already signed in
        // the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.
        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)?.let {
            gotToMainActivity()
        }
    }
```

I am logging the user using an Activity but trying to get the logged-in user in a fragment. I don't know if that causes an issue.

Comment: If you do a google search for the title of your question, you will find that this gets asked on Stack Overflow all the time.

Comment: have you tried `currentUser= FirebaseAuth.instance().currentUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using social login like facebook through firebase, it is also necessary to let Firebase.auth know that you are logged in through facebook login. You would typically follow the facebook sdk steps to add the facebook login button to complete the login and on your login success callback, you would do sth like this to let firebase know of your auth state. This is copied over from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase

```
private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:$token")

    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
}
```

After doing this, Firebase.auth.currentUser should be populated!
I ran into this specifically on Android but I think other platforms would be similar too!

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. My app supports both Firebase Authentication and Google sign-in. 
When logged in with Google `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` was null.

So I have to check either Firebase or GoogleSignIn and use whichever one is non-null.